# Measuring different values in latlong Geotiff whether OTFR enabled or not

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, wgs84

I'm using a GeoTiff file in QGis that has no projection per-se (it uses lat-long coordinates) and WGS84 datum. Further it has an x pixel size of 2.40475e-07 degrees and a y pixel size of -1.99028e-07... so multiplying by the radius of the earth where it is standing according to the WGS84 geoid (6371.30 km) I get a pixel size of 2.6 cm in x and 2.2 cm in y.

Importing directly the file into QGis and measuring the size of a pixel with the Measure Line tool i get exactly those values... so far so good.

But if I enable OTFR in any CRS (inluding the same used by the file, namely lat-long WGS84) when i measure the size of the pixel y get a size of 2.2 in x and 2.2 in y.

Is the pixel size (in degrees) given by the Geotiff as if it were in the equator?

Answer (score 1):

The WGS84 geoid is not a sphere with a constant radius, but rather an ellipsoid.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System, the ellipsoid has `a = 6378137 m` and `b = 6356752 m`.

It seems that without OTFR the distance is calculated using the sphere, and with OTFR using the ellipsoid.